# How does vector work while pushing back a reference of its element to itself?

Tags: c++

I first declare a `vector` of `string` called `test`. Then I push_back `string` `Hello` and `World` and let `a` be a `reference` of `test[0]`.And then I push_back `a` into `test`. However , I printed `a` before and after push_back respectively and observed that `a` became nothing after pushed into `test`. Why `a` becomes nothing? How does the vector work while pushing back a `reference` `(a)` of its element to itself ? Does that mean `a` is no longer a `reference` of `test[0]` ?
Thanks .

Remarks: If I push_back `test[0]` , `a` also becomes nothing. But `test[0]` is still "Hello".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     vector<string> test;
     test.push_back("Hello");
     test.push_back("World");
     string& a = test[0];
     cout << "1"<< a << "\n";
     test.push_back(a);          //or : test.push_back(test[0]);
     cout << "2"<< a << "\n"; 
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ad55df8ce5e2ea8)

output:

```
1Hello
2
```

Update:

I got it ,thanks to answers and comments below. I printed the `size` and `capacity` of `test` and observed that they are both `2` . When `test.push_back(a)`is performed , the vector `test` allocates new memory and copy its old elements to the new memory . Thus `a` , the reference of it old elements , become undefined.

Here is the similar code using `reserve` . I think the reason why `a` becomes undefined is same as my original question. (Let me know if I'm wrong.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     vector<string> test;
     test.push_back("Hello");
     test.push_back("World");
     string& a = test[0];
     cout << "1"<< a << "\n";
     cout << "size:" << test.size() << " capacity:" <<test.capacity() <<"\n";  
     test.reserve(3);       
     cout << "2"<< a << "\n"; 
}
```

output:

```
1Hello
size:2 capacity:2
2
```

Comment: on a `push_back` all iterators, pointers and references to vector element are invalidated (except some cases you did not test for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
test.push_back(a);          //or : test.push_back(test[0]);
```

Adds a copy of `a` as the last element of `test`. The fact that `a` is a reference to an element in `test` is not relevant at all.

After that call, `a` could be dangling reference. Using it as you have in the line

```
 cout << "2"<< a << "\n";
```

is cause for undefined behavior.

`test[0]`, on the other hand, returns a reference to the first element of `test`. It could be a reference to a different object than what `a` references.

Comment: Thanks. But why does the copy of `a` make `a` become dangling reference ? Isn't it just "copy" ? Why does the reference `a` become undefined?Now I replace `test.push_back(a)` with `string b = a` . Doesn't this copy `a` to `b` like my original question? But after copying `a` to `b` , `a` isn't undefined but "Hello" (`test[0]`).

Comment: `std::vector::push_back` may need to allocate memory if its current capacity is not sufficient to hold the new element. When it does, it deletes old memory after copying/moving old objects to new memory. As a consequence, references to old objects might become dangling references.

Answer (score 4):

The `string& a` became undefined due to `vector::push_back` invalidating existing references to the container, per the `std::vector` definition.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back.

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Since you don't know what the capacity of the vector before pushing `a` was, you can't be sure that your reference wasn't invalidated; this is undefined behavior that may "work" in some cases, but can do anything in others.